# How to force JavaMailSenderImpl to use TLS1.2?

Tags: java, email, smtp, tls1.2

Have a JDK7 app running on Tomcat and it does have the following env settings:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

The above setting ensures that we don't use TLS 1.0 when connecting over HTTPS while making API calls etc.

We also use the org.springframework.mail.javamail.**JavaMailSenderImpl** class to send outgoing SMTP email, and use these props:

```
 mail.smtp.auth=false;mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=2525;mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=true;mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

The problem is that the connection to the SMTP email server is failing when it's upgraded to TLS1.2.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake

**Is there a settings or code change that will force the TLS1.2 protocol?**

I did some searching and it looks like these env settings are only for applet and web clients, not for server side apps

```
-Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is the fix for the next guy looking:

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true;
mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2;
```

Comment: And those config values are JavaMail props, right, like those others in code snippet no 2 in the question. (But they aren't `-D...` flags.)

Answer (score 15):

It didn't work for me in one pretty old app and I couldn't realize why. After some research I found that the `javax.mail` version in the app dependencies was 1.4. You must upgrade to at least 1.5.

Answer (score 12):

I needed both Vojtech Zavrel and Sunny's answer in my case. I was running Java 1.8 Spring Boot 1.2.5 and running on Big Sur 11.2.3 and spring version 4.2.1.RELEASE.

After I updated my dependency like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

and I updated my `JavaMailSenderImpl` with

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2"); // Added this line
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", mailUri.getHost());
mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(prop);
```

I saw the `Received fatal alert: protocol_version` error resolve.

Comment: In my case the error was random ("..javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2." returned as an SMTP error by some Microsoft mail server) and didn't go away with `1.5.0-b01`; but upgrading to latest available (`com.sun.mail:javax-mail:1.6.2`) along with the session property, seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: I also have to follow the same steps as @JanakaBandara to resolve the issue. I was using spring boot 2.0.2 and had to update it to 2.0.5

Comment: I also had to upgrade my javax.mail artifact - but I was able to go to 1.4.7 (the last non-beta version I could see on maven central) from 1.4.  Doing that combined with setting the `mail.smtp.ssl.protocols` property worked for me.

Comment: The above java code worked fine but note there is another mandatory property required without which you will get a protocol not found error.
````prop.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");````

Comment: in my case I had to set `prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");`

Answer (score 5):

An update to the most recent version (1.6.2.) of Java Mail also fixes the issue. In my case I upgraded from:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This fixed the error

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2

I was getting from an Outlook SMTP-Server. No property changes needed.